# Shell exit codes inconsistants with simple command

Tags: shell, unix, redirect, exit-code

I have an issue that should not be too hard to solve, I just can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

I need to test if a command is successful or not, and the command needs to be executed from a script. The command is:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000 &> /dev/null
```

Right now there is no server running, so it should always fail. And it does fail when I execute it from a command line. However when I run it from inside a shell script, it fails but the exit code is 0. What could the cause of that be?

Here is the script:

```
if curl 127.0.0.1:5000 &> /dev/null
then
    echo "sucess"
    exit 0
else
    echo "failure"
    exit 1
fi
```

And here is the output:

```
success
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
```

However, it does work as expected if I remove the redirection (I'm quite a beginner in shell code, but the redirection shouldn't also redirect the exit code right? So I really don't know what this means)

here is the code without redirections that works as expected (therefore that indicates a failure and has an exit code of 1):

```
if curl 127.0.0.1:5000
then
    echo "sucess"
    exit 0
else
    echo "failure"
    exit 1
fi
```

Anyone has an idea?

Edit:
I was launching the script with `sh script_name.sh` in zsh. When I use `zsh script_name.sh` it now works normally. I still don't fully understand why but at least it works!

Comment: Interesing, could you share the shell which be used for this?

Comment: I use the command `sh [script_name].sh` in zsh

Comment: Oh now I tried with the command `zsh [script_name].sh`and it works as expected! So I guess it is because if you call your script with another shell's command it might mess with the exit codes? It's weird because it works with `sh` if I don't use redirections. Anyway, now it works, thank you!

Comment: where did you learn to call a script with `sh [script_name].sh` ? This causes many problems. Just have a proper "she-bang" line (`#!/bin/zsh` in your case) and call with `/path/to/script_name.sh [args]` or store the script in a dir included in `$PATH`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"&> /dev/null"* is interpreted differently in Bourne shell (sh), The *"&"* puts the command in background, you can test it with *"sleep 100 &>/dev/null"*. Since it successfully put the command in background, it is a success, and the exit status of the backgrounded command is disregarded.

If you want it to work in Bourne shell (sh), use the traditional syntax *">/dev/null 2>&1"*, and it will work in newer shells as well, i.e. it is more compatible.

In a system where sh is linked to bash, it will work as is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! now I remember that I had effectively seen somewhere that `&>` was a feature from bash 4.